# Missing parent module route url in child module

Tags: angular, angular7, angular-routing, angular7-router

New to Angular and trying to structure my code in modules.
I got an admin module responding to

> /admin

request and now I'm trying to add another child module to the Admin module, called Portfolio Module.

This works, except that I want the portfolio module, to response to

> /admin/portfolio

request. Right now it response to

> /portfolio

request instead.

Here I'm Importing the PortfolioModule

*admin.module.ts*

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { AdminRoutingModule } from  './admin-routing.module';
import { IndexComponent } from './shared/index/index.component';
import {PortfolioModule} from './portfolio/portfolio.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [IndexComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    PortfolioModule,
    AdminRoutingModule
  ]
})
export class AdminModule { }
```

Thinking that I maybe need to define the PortfolioModule as a children route. inside the admin route.

*admin-routing.module.ts*

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { IndexComponent } from './shared/index/index.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'admin',
    component: IndexComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'portfolio',
        /*Maybe add Portfolio Module here?*/
      }        
    ]
  }
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AdminRoutingModule { }
```

Here is my portfolio module, nothing special about it.

*portfolio.module.ts*

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { PortfolioRoutingModule } from './portfolio-routing.module';
import { IndexComponent } from './index/index.component';
import { CreateComponent } from './create/create.component';
import { ListComponent } from './list/list.component';
import { UpdateComponent } from './update/update.component';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [IndexComponent, CreateComponent, ListComponent, UpdateComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    PortfolioRoutingModule
  ]
})
export class PortfolioModule { }
```

And last here is my portfolio routing, maybe I'm missing something here, to tell it to include the parent route.

*portfolio-routing.module.ts*

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { IndexComponent } from './index/index.component';
import { ListComponent } from './list/list.component';
import { CreateComponent } from './create/create.component';
import { UpdateComponent } from './update/update.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'portfolio',
    component: IndexComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'list',
        component: ListComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'create',
        component: CreateComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'update',
        component: UpdateComponent
      }
    ]
  }
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class PortfolioRoutingModule { }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you lazy load, a module the root of the path should be in the routing of the module that is declaring the lazy loaded module.

For instance, `path: 'portfolio'` would be declared as a route in the `admin-routing.module` and your `IndexComponent` for `portfolio-routing.module` would have an empty path (`path: ''`).  Also the `children` attribute is probably not necessary as all routes would be on the same level.

Your routing could look something like this.

#### app-routing.module

```
...
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'admin',
    loadChildren: './admin/admin.module#AdminModule'
  }
]
...
```

#### admin-routing.module

```
...
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: AdminIndexComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'portfolio',
    loadChildren: './portfolio/portfolio.module#PortfolioModule'
  }
]
...
```

#### portfolio-routing.module

```
...
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: PortfolioIndexComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'create',
    component: PortfolioCreateComponent
  }
]
...
```

I also put together a working stackblitz of this example linked below along with the angular guide doc for lazy loading feature modules.

> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bkxpsp
>
> https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules